# How to display 4 images in one figure

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

Assume that I have 4 images, output 1 to 4. I'd like to display all 4 images in one figure.

I know that if I want to display two images next to each other I write

```py
numpy_vertical = np.vstack((output2, output3))

cv2.imshow('Numpy Vertical', numpy_vertical)
# cv2.imshow('Numpy Horizontal', numpy_horizontal)
path = '/path to folder/main_folder'
 
cv2.waitKey()
```

But my question is how can I display 4 images in one figure like this, with axis.

https://3qeqpr26caki16dnhd19sv6by6v-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Plot-of-Augmented-Images-with-a-Horizontal-Flip.png

Comment: Use subplot function from matplotlib

Answer (score 1):

- You can use **Matplotlib** library, but be careful! Open CV library in python reads the images in BGR format(if they are colour images), and Matplotlib plots them in RGB format.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

numpy_vertical = np.vstack((output2, output3))


# cv2.imshow('Numpy Vertical', numpy_vertical)
# cv2.imshow('Numpy Horizontal', numpy_horizontal)
path = '/path to folder/main_folder'
# cv2.waitKey()
im_rgbVertical = cv2.cvtColor(numpy_vertical, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
im_rgbHorizontal = cv2.cvtColor(numpy_horizontal, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

plt.figure(num='your figure name')
plt.subplot('121')
plt.imshow(im_rgbVertical)
plt.title('Vertical')
plt.subplot('122')
plt.imshow(im_rgbHorizontal)
plt.title('Horizontal')
plt.show()
```